# Map return 2 times this same object when should return only 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from API and when I try map array for interesting data my program download for 1st search 2 times this same object, 2nd and another time 6 times.
 I don't know why. I checked useEffect and this function fetch only once time what is expected.
Problem is when I want to show 5 days and I want to show an hourly forecast for each day. 
**What I expect:** map return me 1 array with 5 days 
**What I receive now:** map return me 2 this same arrays with this same 5 days.

Here is code:

### App.js

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Weather from './Weather';
import useSyncFetch from '../services/useSyncFetch';

const App = () => {
  const url = "http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json";
  const key = "*********************";
  const [idCity, setIdCity] = useState();

  const data = useSyncFetch(url + "/sitelist?" + key);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Form
        setIdCity={setIdCity}
        data={data}
      />
      <Weather 
        idCity={idCity}
        url={url}
        apiKey={key}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Form.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Form = ({setIdCity, data}) => {

    const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('');
    
    const findId = (e) =>{
        const cities = data.Locations.Location;
        cities.forEach(city => {
        const userInput = cityName.toLowerCase();
        const dataCitiesName = city.name.toLowerCase();

            if(userInput === dataCitiesName){
                console.log(city.name, city.id)
                return setIdCity(city.id)
            }
        });
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        findId();
    }

    const handleChange = e => {
        setCityName(e.target.value)
    }
    
    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="location">Location: </label>
            <input 
            onChange={handleChange} 
            type="text" 
            name="location" 
            id="location" />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Check</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

### Weather.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Day from './Day';

const Weather = ({ idCity, url, apiKey }) => {

    const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url + `/${idCity}?res=3hourly&` + apiKey)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setLocation(data.SiteRep.DV.Location);
                setIsLoading(false)
            })
    }, [apiKey, idCity, url])

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <h2>Please write location and click check</h2>
        )
    } else if(!isLoading){
        const days = location.Period
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{location.name}</p>
                <p>{location.country}</p>
                {days.map(element => (
                    <Day 
                    key={element.value}
                    days={days}
                    hourlyForecast={element.Rep}
                    date={element.value}
                    />
                ))}
                {console.log(days, "Days")}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
// //Bug is with rerender should be days.map(element => {
//     element.Rep.map(day => )
// }) 

export default Weather;
```

### Day

```
import React from 'react';
import Hours from './Hours'

const Day = ({ days, date, hourlyForecast }) => {

    const dayDate = date.slice(0, 10);
    const forecastForHour = hourlyForecast.map(element => (
        <Hours
         key={element.$}
         hours={hourlyForecast}
         />
    ))
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{dayDate}</p>
            {forecastForHour}
            {console.log(hourlyForecast, "Hours")}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Day;
```

### Hours.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const weatherTypes = [
    { id: 0, weather: "Clear night" },
    { id: 1, weather: "Sunny day" },
    { id: 2, weather: "Partly cloudy (night)" },
    { id: 3, weather: "Partly cloudy (day)" },
    { id: 4, weather: "Not used" },
    { id: 5, weather: "Mist" },
    { id: 6, weather: "Fog" },
    { id: 7, weather: "Cloudy" },
    { id: 8, weather: "Overcast" },
    { id: 9, weather: "Light rain shower (night)" },
    { id: 10, weather: "Light rain shower (day)" },
    { id: 11, weather: "Drizzle" },
    { id: 12, weather: "Light rain" },
    { id: 13, weather: "Heavy rain shower (night)" },
    { id: 14, weather: "Heavy rain shower (day)" },
    { id: 15, weather: "Heavy rain" },
    { id: 16, weather: "Sleet shower (night)" },
    { id: 17, weather: "Sleet shower (day)" },
    { id: 18, weather: "Sleet" },
    { id: 19, weather: "Hail shower (night)" },
    { id: 20, weather: "Hail shower (day)" },
    { id: 21, weather: "Hail" },
    { id: 22, weather: "Light snow shower (night)" },
    { id: 23, weather: "Light snow shower (day)" },
    { id: 24, weather: "Light snow" },
    { id: 25, weather: "Heavy snow shower (night)" },
    { id: 26, weather: "Heavy snow shower (day)" },
    { id: 27, weather: "Heavy snow" },
    { id: 28, weather: "Thunder shower (night)" },
    { id: 29, weather: "Thunder shower (day)" },
    { id: 30, weather: "Thunder" },
]

const Hours = ({ hours }) => {
    let temperature;
    let feelLikeTemperature;
    let wind;
    let weatherType;
    let visibility;
    let UV;
    let time;
    let pop;
    let weatherText;

    const hour = hours.map(element => {

        switch (element.V) {
            case "VP":
                visibility = "Very poor - less than 1 km "
                break;
            case "PO":
                visibility = "Poor - Between 1-4 km "
                break;
            case "MO":
                visibility = "Moderate - Between 4-10 km"
                break;
            case "GO":
                visibility = "Good - Between 10-20 km"
                break;
            case "VG":
                visibility = "Very good - Between 20-40 km"
                break;
            case "EX":
                visibility = "Excellent - More than 40 km"
                break;

            default:
                visibility = "Unknown"
                break;
        }
        if (element.U <= 2) {
            UV = "Low exposure. No protection required. You can safely stay outside"
        } else if (element.U > 2 && element.U < 5) {
            UV = "Moderate exposure. Seek shade during midday hours, cover up and wear sunscreen"
        } else if (element.U === 6 || element.U === 7) {
            UV = "High exposure. Seek shade during midday hours, cover up and wear sunscreen"
        } else if (element.U >= 8 && element.U < 11) {
            UV = "Very high. Avoid being outside during midday hours. Shirt, sunscreen and hat are essential"
        } else {
            UV = "Extreme. Avoid being outside during midday hours. Shirt, sunscreen and hat essential."
        }
        weatherType = element.W;
        temperature = element.T;
        time = element.$/60;
        feelLikeTemperature = element.F;
        wind = element.S;
        pop = element.Pp;
    })

    const checkWeatherType = weatherTypes.map(type=>{
        // console.log(weatherType)
        if(weatherType === type.id) return weatherText = type.weather;
        else return weatherText=type.weather;
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Time {time < 10 ? "0" + time + ":00" : time + ":00"}</p>
            <p>Temperature: {temperature} Celcius</p>
            <p>Feel like temperature: {feelLikeTemperature} Celcius</p>
            <p>Wind: {wind} mph</p>
            <p>Weather Type: {weatherText}</p>
            <p>Visibility: {visibility}</p>
            <p>Max UV index: {UV}</p>
            <p>Precipitation Probability: {pop} %</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Hours;
```

Comment: Just a hint; you should probably remove your API keys when posting publicly.  Wouldn't want anyone to get it from you :D.

Comment: I think you posted the same component twice. Is all of this code relevant to the problem? It seems like there's a lot of extra to sift through...

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Ok I did

Comment: @Brian Thompson. Not all. Only App.js with Weather. When I put console.log(days) in map function in Weather this shows me 2 times this same array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap ‘useSyncFetch’ within ‘useEffect’ otherwise this function is called on each render.